# How to add elements to a sorted linked list?

Tags: java

while loop (so that while the current element in the list is less than the parameter, go to the next element)....but how do I do this?  I can't do < or compareTo, so I'm not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `add(..)` method semantics is usually to add to the end of the list. So you can simply hold a reference to the `tail` node (in addition to `head`), and insert after it. Apart from that, addition at a specified position is O(n) for a linked-list - you have to loop through the elements one by one until you reach the target index.